# What is the meaning behind this SQL Statement? ISNULL(Status,0) & 128 = 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Some of the stored procedures in my application, using `WHERE` condition like this:

```
ISNULL(Status,0) & 128 = 0
```

What exactly does it mean or how it compares? I understand `isnull` condition, but single `&` operator what purpose, want to know. Can any one suggest me?

Comment: What part is it you don't understand `ISNULL`, `& 128` or `= 0`? I'm not sure what condition means in this context, and there *shouldn't* be anything prior to the `ISNULL` for that clause. I'd also avoid using `ISNULL` in a `WHERE`.

Answer (score 5):

The following condition:

```
ISNULL(Status,0) & 128 = 0
```

Evaluates whethere the 8th bit of `Status` (=128) is **not** set.

Using the `&` operator performs a bitwise `AND` to evaluate whether two values share the same bits.

In the case of the above you can break it down as so:

- Use the value of `Status` or 0 if `Status` is `NULL`
- Bitwise `AND` this value with 128
- Return true if the bitwise `AND` returns `0` (so the bit is NOT set)

Incidentally, if the bit on `Status` was set, this would return `128` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanations:**

The statement `ISNULL(Status, 0) & 128 = 0` checks if the `8th` bit of the `Status` column is equal to `1`. [ISNULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) replaces NULL with the specified replacement value and [& (bitwise AND)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) performs a bitwise logical AND operation between two integer values.

One explanation for this check is that sometimes is more appropriate to store multiple bit values in one column, instead of creating multiple bit columns for each value. This approach is based on additional calculation using the `POWER` function. After that, the `& (BITWISE AND)` operator is needed to get the value for each stored switch.

**Example:**

The next example, based on the statement in the question, shows how to store the values for 7 switches, in one column, and then check the status for a given switch.

```
-- Calculation
DECLARE @switch int
SELECT @switch = (
   POWER(2 * 0, 1) +  -- switch 1 is off
   POWER(2 * 0, 2) +  -- switch 2 is off
   POWER(2 * 0, 3) +  -- switch 3 is off
   POWER(2 * 0, 4) +  -- switch 4 is off
   POWER(2 * 0, 5) +  -- switch 5 is off
   POWER(2 * 0, 6) +  -- switch 6 is off
   POWER(2 * 1, 7)    -- switch 7 is on
)   

-- Check for switch 7. 128 is equal to POWER(2, 7)
IF ISNULL(@switch, 0) & 128 = 0 PRINT 'OFF' ELSE PRINT 'ON'

-- All checks
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(@switch, 0) & POWER(2, 1) /* or 2 */   = 0 THEN 'Switch1 is OFF' ELSE 'Switch1 IS ON' END,
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(@switch, 0) & POWER(2, 2) /* or 4 */   = 0 THEN 'Switch2 is OFF' ELSE 'Switch2 IS ON' END,
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(@switch, 0) & POWER(2, 3) /* or 8 */   = 0 THEN 'Switch3 is OFF' ELSE 'Switch3 IS ON' END,
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(@switch, 0) & POWER(2, 4) /* or 16 */  = 0 THEN 'Switch4 is OFF' ELSE 'Switch4 IS ON' END,
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(@switch, 0) & POWER(2, 5) /* or 32 */  = 0 THEN 'Switch5 is OFF' ELSE 'Switch5 IS ON' END,
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(@switch, 0) & POWER(2, 6) /* or 64 */  = 0 THEN 'Switch6 is OFF' ELSE 'Switch6 IS ON' END,
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(@switch, 0) & POWER(2, 7) /* or 128 */ = 0 THEN 'Switch7 is OFF' ELSE 'Switch7 IS ON' END
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` is [& (Bitwise AND) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and is defined as:

> Performs a bitwise logical AND operation between two integer values.
>
> ...
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The & bitwise operator performs a bitwise logical AND between the two expressions, taking each corresponding bit for both expressions. The bits in the result are set to 1 if and only if both bits (for the current bit being resolved) in the input expressions have a value of 1; otherwise, the bit in the result is set to 0.
>
> If the left and right expressions have different integer data types (for example, the left expression is smallint and the right expression is int), the argument of the smaller data type is converted to the larger data type. In this case, the smallintexpression is converted to an int.

In this case, when the value of `Status` have a `1` for the bit value 128 (`10000000`) then the condition would be false. So numbers such as `128`-`255` would be not meet the `WHERE` clause requirement, or numbers like `412` (`0110011100`), as the bit representing 128 has the value `1`.

On a side note, I would personally write the above as:

```
WHERE (Status & 128 = 0 OR Status IS NULL)
```